# Search for entire name based on three columns with LINQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I am trying to make a search method using LINQ in Visual Studio. In my database, I have the three fields "Firstname", "LastNamePrefix" and "Lastname". My searchstring is Searchtext. How can I make a simple LINQ query which searches all the fields?

What I have at the moment is this:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(input.SearchText) || x.LastNamePrefix.Contains(input.SearchText) || x.LastName.Contains(input.SearchText));
```

With this I come really close to the solution but when I try to combine Firstname with LastNamePrefix and Lastname, I don't get any result.

For example with the name Jan van Lauw:

```
I search Jan. It works
I search van. It works
I search Lauw. It works
I search Jan van Lauw. No results.
```

I tried to make a column which combines the three columns to a fullname with the following function:

```
public static string CreateFullname(string firstName, string lastNamePrefix, string lastName)
{
    return $"{firstName} {lastNamePrefix} {lastName}".Replace("  ", " ").Trim();
}
```

If I try to use this column like the code below, I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains(input.SearchText));
```

How can search in multiple columns?

Comment: Look at my comment below, your FullName suggestion is wrong (not only the syntax)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use custom (not mapped) properties, like `FullName`, in queries, but you can combine your properties inline:

```
query.Where(x => (x.FirstName.Trim() + " " + x.LastNamePrefix.Trim() + " " + x.LastName.Trim()).Trim().Contains(input.SearchText));
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to entities cannot build a query when you use calculated property.
Try using in-place string concatenation in your query.

I am not sure if LINQ to Entities is able to translate this expression to SQL "like" query, but I used this approach in Entity Framework.

```
query = query
    .Where(x => (x.FirstName + " " + x.LastNamePrefix + " " + x.LastName).Contains(input.SearchText));
```

You can just combine two OR queries to make your search more flexible:

```
query = query
    .Where(x => (x.FirstName + " " + x.LastNamePrefix + " " + x.LastName).Contains(input.SearchText) 
              || (x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName).Contains(input.SearchText));
```

Comment: this works.GREAT! Now i got a second problem that is sort of related to the question. Most of the time the LastNamePrefix is empty. How can i include this exception in the sql?

Comment: @B.Termeer I have updated my answer. Does this suit your needs? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion to combine the names to full name and remove the " " is wrong,
that why:

> **SearchText**: 'abc'
>
> **FirstName**: 'ab'
>
> **LastNamePrefix**: 'c'
>
> **LastName**: 'doesn't matter'

The result you wish is false, because there is no 'abc' inside First Name or LastNamePrefix and LastName, but in your suggestion it will be accepted.

You searching by 3 params, you would have to compare those params